# How to send json object as html with sendgrid api

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send an email message using sendgrid API. I want the body of the message to include a json object formatted as HTML.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the body of the email instead looks like this:

{
"glossary": {
"title": "example glossary",
"GlossDiv": {
"title": "S",
"GlossList": {
"GlossEntry": {
"ID": "SGML",
"SortAs": "SGML",
"GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
"Acronym": "SGML",
"Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
"GlossDef": {
"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
},
"GlossSee": "markup"
}
}
}
}
}

When I stringify a json object and send as HTML with the sendgrid API, the email body is just one long text string, which is difficult to read :( I also tried NPM package [retty-print-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-print-json)

All of these produce the same result: the email body is just one long text string

**stringify**

```
let html = stringify.JSON(getStats);   
        const msg = {
            to: 'foo@foo.com',         
            from: 'foo@foo.com', 
            subject: datasetTitle,
            html: html
        }
```

**prettyPrintJson**

```
let html = prettyPrintJson.toHtml(getStats);
        const msg = {
            to: 'foo@foo.com',         
            from: 'foo@foo.com', 
            subject: datasetTitle,
            html: html
        }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the end result that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace including line breaks, collapse in HTML by default. Wrap the pretty-printed JSON in `<pre></pre>` and the output should be presented correctly. You don't need a package to add the line breaks, just specify the extra params when serializing `JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4)`